# How to specific value from ajax response?

Tags: ajax

ajax code:

```
    function dropdown(){

       $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '<?php echo Mage::getUrl('rma/index/view')?>',
            data:   $('#order').serialize()  ,
            success: function(response){
            alert(response);

            }
        });  return false;

        }
```

response is like this

```
 Array
 (
  [0] => test
  [1] => 1.0000
  [2] => test
 )
```

now i want array[0] value how to get specific value?

Comment: I think this may be off-topic because this is about javascript in general and not Magento.

Answer (score 2):

I assume the action you call in the url returns an array like this:

```
$response = array('test', 1.0000, 'test');
$this->getResponse()->setBody($response);
```

You need to return the response as a json, and then you will be able to read it in javascript.

```
$response = array('test', 1.0000, 'test');
$this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($response));
```

Then in your js you can do this:

```
success: function(response){
    response = response.toJSON();
    var whatYouNeed = response[0]; //this is what you are looking for.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ND14,
I guess that you have print array on this controller  and please instead of **print array here just return the array as json object**.

```
Array
 (
  [0] => test
  [1] => 1.0000
  [2] => test
 )
```

**Like:**

Guess that $result is  a array which give the data in array   format

```
$this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
```

**Here:** `Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode()` is `encode` an array to `json`. and  `$this->getResponse()->setBody()` set response

for getting value from data ajax success try  this code

```
     onSuccess:function(transport){
            var response=transport.responseText.evalJSON(true);

}
```

**responseText.evalJSON(true)** is valued the json return to json data

you can get data by

```
console.log(response.0);
console.log(response.1);

console.log(response.0);
console.log(response.2);
```

Comment: i am add my controller please tell me how to do this as json because i don't know how to use json